# How do I change master page for a specific page in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007, master-pages

How can I apply a different master page for two pages within a SharePoint site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new master page, say `custom2.master`.

Then go to the page whose master page you wish to alter. Find the <%@ Page %> directive:

`<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="_catalogs/masterpage/<<custom2.master>>"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %><%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>`

Update its virtual URL in above tag under the `MasterPageFile` attribute